# How to generate different headers in first page and other pages in poi word XWPF?

Tags: apache-poi

I want to generate different headers in first page and other pages in poi word, So I used XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.FIRST and XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT. when I using XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT I can insert my header successfully, but when I change to XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.FIRST, I cannot see there is a header in my first page, this is my code in below, what's wrong with it? thanks!

```
XWPFHeader header = headerFooterPolicy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.FIRST);
      paragraph = header.createParagraph();
      paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
      run = paragraph.createRun();  
      run.setText("header");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That there is a different header set for first page only, means not that this header will also be shown. In `Word` GUI there is a checkbox `[x] Different First Page` in `Header & Footer Tools` to achieve that.

And according [Office Open XML Part 4 - Markup Language Reference](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/Office%20Open%20XML%20Part%204%20-%20Markup%20Language%20Reference.pdf#page=838) there must a boolean XML element `titlePg` be set to determine that there is a title page present.

In actual final `apache poi` version 3.15 this XML element `titlePg` can only be set using underlying low level objects using `doc.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr().addNewTitlePg();`.

But `apache poi` version 3.16 Beta 2 has `doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);` which sets `titlePg` flag in XML.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordHeaderFooterDifferent {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument doc= new XWPFDocument();

  // the body content
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The Body:");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 1");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 2");

  paragraph = doc.createParagraph();
  run=paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE); 
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum.... page 3");

  // create first page header
  XWPFHeader header = doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);

  paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The first page header:");

  // create default page header
  header = doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = header.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The default page header:");

  // create footer
  XWPFFooter footer = doc.createFooter(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

  paragraph = footer.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Page ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("PAGE \\* MERGEFORMAT");
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText(" of ");
  paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* MERGEFORMAT");

  doc.write(new FileOutputStream("CreateWordHeaderFooterDifferent.docx"));

 }
}
```

But in my opinion the setting `titlePg` flag in XML automatically while `HeaderFooterType.FIRST` is created is not correct. Since `Word` can toggle between  `[x] Different First Page` and  `[] Different First Page`, `apache poi` should also be able to do so. So the setting the `titlePg` flag should be a method in `XWPFDocument`.

Comment: In Word, you are unable to add a first page header or footer unless you first check the flag. It makes Word easier to use when there are not a bunch of options available that won't appear in the document. In POI we have a different situation. I can simply add a First page header, and ease of use says I shouldn't have to know that I have to set a special flag for that header to appear. I don't want to force the user to know the underlying structures to use them. So if I add a first page header or footer, the `titlePg` should automatically be set. This follows the principle of least surprise.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in that class to tell Word to display different first page headers. You will need the most recent version of POI, and then create the header from XWPFDocument using:

```
XWPFDocument.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
```

Otherwise you need to break into the CT classes and in the section properties set the `titlePg` property. I don't recommend this approach though as it is likely to change.

Comment: Thank you so much, you answer is very valuable!

Comment: Hi, I am sorry to trouble you again. I want to set header and footer 's position. Header from top: 45.4 pt, Footer from bottom: 28.4 pt as we can see in Header & Footer Tools menu when we open a word file. thanks!

Comment: Maybe I should set pageSize? paragraph.getCTP().addNewFldSimple().setInstr("NUMPAGES \\* MERGEFORMAT"); is the total number of page, but how can I set the number's style, like fontSize(12)?

Comment: These are different questions, Please post them as such, that way someone else can find them.