# Getting "A text/xml declaration may occur only at the very beginning of input" in Word 2013 after adding header in XWPFDocument

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, xwpf

I have used the following code to write my header. The document opens in word 2007 and open office but would not open in word 2013. Could anyone please suggest a possible workaround?

```
CTSectPr sectPr = docx.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
            XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy = new XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy(docx, sectPr);

CTP ctpHeader = CTP.Factory.newInstance();
            CTR ctrHeader = ctpHeader.addNewR();
            CTText ctHeader = ctrHeader.addNewT();
            String headerText = Driver.sClientName+" Case : "+Driver.sCaseID;
            ctHeader.setStringValue(headerText);    
            XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = new XWPFParagraph(ctpHeader, docx);
            headerParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
            XWPFParagraph[] parsHeader = new XWPFParagraph[1];
            parsHeader[0] = headerParagraph;
            policy.createHeader(XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.DEFAULT, parsHeader);
```

PS :I'm using the latest poi jars(version 3.16)

Comment: If you are using current `apache poi` version, then your code can be simplified using [XWPFDocument.createHeader](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#createHeader(org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType)) and [XWPFDocument.createFooter](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#createFooter(org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType)). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43131641/how-to-generate-different-headers-in-first-page-and-other-pages-in-poi-word-xwpf/43140073#43140073 for an example.

Comment: I am using poi-3.16-beta2 jars and also ooxml-schemas-1.3jar but I still get an error at createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT) as "The method createHeader(HeaderFooterType) is undefined for the type XWPFDocumnent " so I used XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy.createHeader . Could you suggest what could be wrong here?

Comment: The code is tested and works for me using apache poi version 3.16 Beta 2. Please check that you are not only using poi-3.16-beta2.jar but also **all** other jars from version 3.16 Beta 2 and **only** from that version. **Don't** mix up jars from different apache poi versions! See https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006 and https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204.

Comment: POI 3.16 final was just released. You may want to use that. Make sure all jars are from the same release.

Comment: Thank you for the advises. I had mixed up the jars. Its working now!